# FragmentResultAPI with Fragments from different Navigation graphs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have FragmentA (belongs to `main_nav_graph`) whose layout contains a `FragmentContainerView` in which I load a `secondary_nav_graph`. FragmentB (child fragment) to be loaded in the container registers a `fragmentResultListener` in order to be triggered once a button from FragmentA (parent fragment) is clicked and consequently receive data from parent. **This is not working because children fragment belong to a different navigation graph**, in my case the secondary_nav_graph.

If the children fragments belong to no navigation graph and are loaded in the container by using the traditional way by calling inside the parent: `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new FragmentB()).commit();` it is going to work correctly.

Any idea how to make it work by having the children Fragment in a different `Navigation graph`?